# Unable to get nested array of objects from json-server

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest, json-server

I am trying to get array of objects from one of the nested JSON properties `fields` through the `json-server`, but I am getting 404 error.

When I access the URL in the browser 'http://localhost:4001/templates/5f105f243c076f3a82c95353' I get the JSON as mentioned in the `db.json`, but when I try to access this URL 'http://localhost:4001/templates/5f105f243c076f3a82c95353/fields' I am getting 404 error.

I believe from the `db.json` file, as `fields` array is a part of template so `/fields` followed by the base URL of the particular template (http://localhost:4001/templates/5f105f243c076f3a82c95353) should work but it is not working, please help me.

db.json file

```
{
  "id": "5f105f243c076f3a82c95353",
  "templateIdName": "DNIS Groups",
  "templateDisplayName": "DNIS Groups Template",
  "templateDescription": "Template for DNIS Groups",
  "fieldCounter": 2,
  "fields": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "fieldIdName": "OutageGroup",
      "fieldDisplayName": "Outage Group",
      "description": "Outage Group",
      "type": "MultiList",
      "values": [
        {
          "listValue": "2803",
          "listDisplay": "Wire Down"
        },
        {
          "listValue": "2804",
          "listDisplay": "Streetlight Outage"
        }
      ],
      "initialValue": "2803",
      "lockValue": "false",
      "requireValue": "true",
      "uniqueField": "true",
      "autoFilter": "false",
      "hideInList": "false",
      "indexField": "true"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "fieldIdName": "ProtectLinesGroups",
      "fieldDisplayName": "Protect Lines Group",
      "description": "Protect Lines Group",
      "type": "MultiList",
      "values": [
        {
          "listValue": "2814",
          "listDisplay": "Cover Lines"
        },
        {
          "listValue": "2815",
          "listDisplay": "Voltage"
        }
      ],
      "initialValue": "2814",
      "lockValue": "false",
      "requireValue": "true",
      "uniqueField": "false",
      "autoFilter": "false",
      "hideInList": "false",
      "indexField": "false"
    }
  ]
}
```

routes.json file

```
{
  "/webservice/:clientId/dblookup/template": "/templates",
  "/webservice/:clientid/dblookup/template/:id": "/templates/:id",
  "/webservice/:clientid/dblookup/template/:id/fields": "/templates/:id/fields"
}
```

Comment: Hi Siddesh, did you find the answer to your question?

Comment: @Varun Yes, Actually JSON-Server don't have the provision to access the nested resources, it can only access resources which are defined as the top level properties in the file, in this example the top level property will be `templates` and I can access that using `http://localhost:4001/templates` but I cannot access the nested property `values` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually JSON-Server don't have the provision to access the nested resources, it can only access resources which are defined as the top level properties in the file, in this example the top level property will be `templates` and I can access that using `http://localhost:4001/templates` but I cannot access the nested property `values` here as `http://localhost:4001/templates/2/values` it gives `404 not found` error.

Comment: That's an issue which should be adress by maintainers of json-server no?